# 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH in py file

Tags: python, selenium

I am facing a weird problem when opening selenium from .py files but no issue from terminal

terminal

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/timmy/chromedriver') #Works
```

.py file

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/timmy/chromedriver',) #options=options)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/timmy/email/google.py", line 34, in shot
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/timmy/chromedriver',) #options=options)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I had some options when launching it in py file (headless, size...) I thought it affected it but still the same issue after I removed the options.

any help is appreciated

Comment: There is a comma after chromedriver. Could you please check it again by removing the ,

Answer (score 0):

make sure chromedriver.exe is copied into the folder specified by `executable_path`
, try to provide full path and add the exe extension to chromedriver.
for example: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\home\timmy\chromedriver.exe')`